# How do I replace all error values in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column which is populated using Index and Match functions and it results in a N/A value when the value is not found. I want to be able to replace all such error values from the column by a special value. I want to do this in VBA code. Any help?

I do not want to rewrite the function with an IF logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really could do this without VBA, by the following:

`IFERROR(myIndexMatchFormula,"special value")`

If you really need a VBA solution, try something like the below. It will find all the error cells in your range and replace with something of your choice. No `If` statements, no loops!

```
Option Explicit

Sub replaceErrors()

Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16) ' -> replace with your specific range

rng.Value = "special values" '-> place what you want here

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for giving both solutions :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, excellent and thanks a lot. I know that I could IFERROR, but I still wanted to understand how to do this using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

`Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Value = ""`
can replace all errors in column E, as an example.
However, unfortunately, specialcells always throws an error if it finds nothing, so you *must* catch this error via some `on error ...`

Answer (score 0):

If `r` is the range which needs to be examined, you can always use the following to identify if the value in the cell is "N/A"

```
If r.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
    ... ' do something
Else
    ... ' do something else
Endif
```

Comment: Thanks Konstant. The problem here is that I have to use a loop, which is what I wanted to avoid. What does CVErr do?